Downloading the Zika Virus Genome Data Using Bioconductor
I am currently taking a datacamp course on the bioconductor package. There's a section where you use the zika genome using the BioStrings package. I'm wondering where I could load this variable? The course says the genome was downloaded from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_012532.1. Inside of datacamp if I do dput(zikaVirus) (the variable in the session is zikaVirus I get
new("DNAStringSet", pool = new("SharedRaw_Pool", xp_list = list(
    <pointer: (nil)>), .link_to_cached_object_list = list(<environment>)), 
    ranges = new("GroupedIRanges", group = 1L, start = 1L, width = 10794L, 
        NAMES = "NC_012532.1 Zika virus isolate ZIKV/Monkey/Uganda/MR766/1947, complete genome", 
        elementType = "ANY", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()), 
    elementType = "DNAString", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list())

which I can't use in R to recreate the variable.

Try this:
library(rentrez)
library(Biostrings)

tmp <- tempfile()

writeLines(
  entrez_fetch(
    db = "nuccore",
    id = "NC_012532.1",
    rettype = "fasta",
    retmode = "text"
  ),
  tmp
)

dna <- readDNAStringSet(tmp, format = "fasta")

Check result:
> print(dna)
DNAStringSet object of length 1:
    width seq                                                                   names               
[1] 10794 AGTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAGTCAG...TCGGCGGCCGGTGTGGGGAAATCCATGGTTTCT NC_012532.1 Zika ...

> dput(dna)
new("DNAStringSet", pool = new("SharedRaw_Pool", xp_list = list(
    <pointer: (nil)>), .link_to_cached_object_list = list(<environment>)), 
    ranges = new("GroupedIRanges", group = 1L, start = 1L, width = 10794L, 
        NAMES = "NC_012532.1 Zika virus, complete genome", elementType = "ANY", 
        elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()), elementType = "DNAString", 
    elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list())


Thank worked! Thanks!
